# how to set SharedArrayBuffer type bufferData in webgl?

Tags: webgl, shader, sharedarraybuffer

I try to use SharedArrayBuffer as a bufferData in webgl.

[MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferData) tell me that can be possible.

I just Change"ArrayBuffer" to "SharedArrayBuffer" 
why my code spit out error.

> [.WebGL-0x7fc1c209b800]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays:
>   attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/callin/pen/WLJdpq)
```

Answer (score 1):

I change second parameter of "bufferData()" from sharedArraybuffer to view.
It's weird!

**original error code**

```js
        NODE_COUNT = 1
        storage = new SharedArrayBuffer( BYTES_PER_NODE * NODE_COUNT )
        console.log 'storage', storage.byteLength
        position = new Float32Array(storage)

        position.set([-.5,.3], 0)

        positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, storage, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

**error fixed code**

```js
        NODE_COUNT = 1
        storage = new SharedArrayBuffer( BYTES_PER_NODE * NODE_COUNT )
        console.log 'storage', storage.byteLength
        position = new Float32Array(storage)

        position.set([-.5,.3], 0)

        positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, position, gl.STATIC_DRAW); # <-- error fixed
```